# WPF Data Binding to a non-property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'd like to be able to bind WPF form elements to something other than a property, or at least, a more advanced property.  As far as I know, WPF forms will only bind to public properties.

For example, making a seating chart for an airplane, its quite cumbersome to create properties for all the different passengers:

```
Plane.Seat1A
Plane.Seat1B
Plane.Seat2A
Plane.Seat2B
Plane.Seat3A
Plane.Seat3B
etc....
```

I would much rather bind to an array indexed by a string, for example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Seat["2A"] }" .... />
```

Is there anything that would approximate this behavior in WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your example will work if you remove the quotes from around "2A".  Here is [an article](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/03/08/binding-to-a-dictionary-in-wpf-and-silverlight).

Comment: I suppose it will only work if Seat implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or perhaps if it has an indexer.

Comment: Isn't that what abelenky says he has?